# Statistics module not logging content views after upgrade

Tags: nodes

I recently upgraded my news blog from 8.4.0 to 8.6.1 and the major issue I have is that the statistics module is not logging the content views any more. The old articles seem to have stack in the same count number and the new articles not showing up in teaser links as they are stuck to zero.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I cleared cache but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with missing php file in theme folder and that caused the issue. When we added the file then the counter worked as expected.